# trying to use git fetch to update my non-master branch to source

Tags: git, github, git-fork, upstream-branch

I have used the steps outlined [here](https://medium.com/@sahoosunilkumar/how-to-update-a-fork-in-git-95a7daadc14e) to successfully update my master branch of the fork. So the master branch of the fork is now even with the original source's master.

I have several different branches and I wanted to make one of them (called new_branch) also even with the original source's master.  So I modified the steps outlined at the link the following way.

`git fetch upstream` (step 4 at the link)

`git checkout new_branch` (step 5)

`git merge upstream/new_branch` (step 6)

Step 6 produces `merge: upstream/new_branch - not something we can merge` in the terminal

I still went ahead with the next step.

`git push origin new_branch` (step 7)

After step 7 all I get is `Everything up-to-date`.
However, github branch `new_branch' still says it is 41 commits behind the source of the fork.

Is it not possible to bring your non-master branch up to date with the source of the fork?

*I ran `git fetch` and `git branch -r` to see what I have.  (I did run `git fetch` before though)

[image]

Comment: What branch were you on when you checked out on step 5? Did `new_branch` exist already locally? Did it exist on `upstream` already?

Comment: @xdhmoore I cloned `new_branch` on my github repo by entering `git clone -b new_branch --single-branch https://github.com/blackwidoq/datahub-learn.git` in the terminal. So yeah I actually started with just `new_branch`.  After cloning, I entered `git remote add upstream https://github.com/figment-networks/datahub-learn.git`. So I did have `upstream`.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to merge from master into your new_branch (something like `git checkout new_branch; git merge master`, and then push to `upstream`.

Comment: The complaint about `upstream/new_branch` indicates that your local repository lacks an `upstream/new_branch`. Run `git branch -r` and see what `upstream/*` names you have. (And, given what you've said in comments here, it sounds like you never did `git fetch upstream`. But if you did, something appears to have gone wrong here.)

Comment: Going to the upstream link you posted above, I don't see a `new_branch`, but I do on the origin link...

Comment: @xdhmoore `new_branch` is on my local repo (https://github.com/blackwidoq/datahub-learn/tree/new_branch)

Comment: @torek  I ran what you suggested. I posted a screenshot of what I saw above.  I did enter `git fetch upstream` though...

Comment: Ah, so you did run `git fetch upstream` but there's no `new_branch` *on* `upstream`, so you did not get an `upstream/new_branch` in your own local repository. I think (on re-reading the question) that this makes sense: you never created a branch named `new_branch` on `upstream`. (I'm pretty tired, need to go to bed, not following carefully here.)

Comment: @torek So does this mean when I run `git fetch upstream`, it only updates my `master` branch of my local repo since I do have a branch called `master`? good night!

Comment: When you run `git fetch upstream`, your Git: (1) Looks up the name `upstream` to get a URL. (2) Uses that URL to phone up another Git. (3) Talks with the other Git: gets their branch names and commit hash IDs. (4) Obtains, from that Git, by commit hash ID, any new *commits* they have that you don't, and stores those in your repository. (5) Updates your *remote-tracking* names by updating or creating each `upstream/*` name according to each of their *branch* names.

Comment: The end result is that you now have all the same *commits* they do, and can use *your* `upstream/*` names to refer to the same commits that they call by their *branch* names. That's how you can use their commits, and/or send their commits to the Git repository you call `origin`, and so on.

Comment: Git isn't about *branches* (or branch names, to be precise), and it isn't about *files*, because it's really all about the commits. You use branch names, and other names, to *find* commits. Commits *hold* files. But it's all about the commits: the commits, with their unique-to-each-commit hash ID, are the real currency in Git.

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

You need to *rebase* your commits, typically using `upstream/master`.  You may then need to use `git push --force-with-lease` or similar to update your `origin`'s `new_branch`, which is your `origin/new_branch`.  See the long answer for details.

## Long

This is all fairly complicated, so here is a capsule summary:

- There are *three* Git repositories involved here.  We can call them Repo-A, Repo-B, and Repo-C.  Two have a URL, though, over on `github.com`.  For sanity in terms of referring to each of the three repositories, let's use their names as seen from *your* repository, on your computer:

  - (no name): the local repository, which we'll just call `laptop` when we need a name;
  - `origin`: a GitHub repository to which you can write directly; and
  - `upstream`: a GitHub repository to which you can't write, but where you can generate a "pull request" using GitHub's ability to do that.
- Each repository has *its own* branches, but all repositories *share* the commits—at least, those that they've seen from other Git repositories.
- We *find* a commit by its hash ID.  The hash ID (or *object ID* in Git terms), in a sense, *is* the commit.  But these things are not user friendly.
- So, we (humans) find a *hash ID* using a name.  But the names are *not* shared across repositories.  At most they're *copied*.  The sharing, if any, is a result of updating some name.  So, in an important sense, they're not shared.
- To transfer commits *between* `laptop` and `origin`, in whatever direction we like, we can use `git fetch` and `git push`.
- To transfer commits between `laptop` and `upstream`, we're only *allowed* to use `git fetch`.

Now, keeping in mind that we find commits by some sort of *name*, let's note that there are lots of kinds of names.  In your own repository on `laptop`, you have *full and total control* over all these names, so you can do anything you want.  For your own sanity, there are certain patterns you'll want to follow.

In the repository named `origin`, you have rather less control over names, but we'll see how you can use `git push` to affect *its* **branch** names.  In the repository named `upstream` you have essentially *no* control over names.

Note that I'm completely ignoring *tags* here.  They complicate the picture a bit, and this is already quite long.

### Fetch, push, and remote-tracking names

Let's talk now about `git fetch` and `git push`.  I'm going to assume you know how commits work and how Git finds commits, by starting from the *last* commit in a branch and working backwards, and that when we `git checkout` some branch by name (or do the same thing with `git switch`) and then make *new* commits, Git updates the *branch name* to hold the *new* commit's hash ID.  The new commit points back to the commit that *was* the last one in the branch, so the branch has automatically been extended by this operation.  This all uses the word *branch*, which is quite ambiguous when using Git, in a rather cavalier and presumptive manner, assuming that the reader can figure out which of any number of different and perhaps even contradictory definitions of *branch* might apply.

What I *won't* assume here is that you know about remote-tracking names, since a lot of your original question hinges on these.  So let's talk about these.  Let's also define *remote*, since it's involved.

A *remote* is just a short name for another Git repository.  We already see that we have two remotes in `laptop`: the name `origin` refers to your fork on GitHub, and the name `upstream` refers to *another* repository on GitHub, from which you created your fork.  A remote always stores a URL, but it also acts as a prefix for these remote-tracking names.

A *remote-tracking name*—which Git calls a *remote-tracking branch name*, but look at how badly the word *branch* is already abused; let's give that poor word a rest here—is a name that your (`laptop`) Git creates and updates based on some *branch* name as seen in some *other Git repository*.

Remember, again, that a *branch name*—as seen in any Git repository, whether it's `laptop`, `origin`, or `upstream`—holds the *hash ID* of a *tip commit*.  So no matter which of the three repositories we look at, we have some string of commits that ends with the most recent:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--branch
```

where `H` is the hash ID of the *most recent* commit on that branch.  If this is all in your local laptop repository, you can see these commits with `git log` or some other commit viewer.

#### Your first goal is to *get all the commits*, which means `git fetch`

In order to fuss around with commits, we need to *have* them.  You have *total control* over the repository on your laptop, so that's where we'd like to have them.  We will *get* these commits with `git fetch`.

What `git fetch` needs is the *name of the repository you want to get commits from*.  That is, we'll pick one of your *remotes:* `origin` or `upstream`.  Your Git will use the stored URL to call up a Git over on GitHub and connect it to one of those repositories.

Like your local Git, the Git you call up—the corresponding repository, really, but let's just pretend that each Git is a person who does this sort of work—can see branch names and commit hash IDs.  With `git fetch`, your Git asks them to report back to you *all* their branch names and those hash IDs.  Your Git can therefore see their Git's name-and-ID pairs.

For each of these IDs, your Git can now check to see if you have this commit.  If you do, great!  There's nothing more to do.  But if you *don't*, well, your Git *wants* this commit, and their Git is happy to give it to you.  Their Git is obligated to offer you any commits that go *with* that commit (parents), and your Git can check to see if you have those, and ask for them too, or say *no thanks, already have that one* as appropriate.  Since this repeats for every *branch* name that they offer,<sup>1</sup> you wind up having them send you every commit that they have, that you don't.  At the end of this "get all the commits" process, you now have *all of their commits*.

We noted earlier, though, that hash IDs are terrible for humans.  That's why *their* Git has *their* branch names in the first place.  It would be nice, would it not, if *your* Git could refer to *their* branch names too?  So that's what your Git does: it *copies their names*, but *changes* them.  You have *your* branch names, and they have theirs.  Your Git doesn't dare overwrite *your* branch names with their information.  Instead, your Git takes their *branch* names and turns them into your *remote-tracking* names.

To do this, your Git just shoves the name of the remote, and a slash, in front of their names.<sup>2</sup>  Their `master` becomes your `origin/master`, if we're having Git fetch from `origin`, or your `upstream/master`, if we're having Git fetch from `upstream`.

Once this is all done, your Git *disconnects* from their Git.  Their Git can now update their *branch* names, and if and when they do, your Git's remote-tracking names are out of date.  This does happen, all the time; to fix it, you just run `git fetch` again, to `origin` to update your `origin/*` names, and to `upstream` to update your `upstream/*` names.  But while you're disconnected, you still have all the commits, *and* your Git remembers where *their* Git's branches are.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you set up a *single-branch* clone, your Git only asks them about that one branch, and hence you don't get everything.  The point of a single-branch clone is ... well, generally to save space and time, but they don't save that much of either one on their own, so until you are really familiar with Git, avoid single-branch clones.

<sup>2</sup>Technically it's more complicated than this, which sort of helps if you accidentally name your own branch `origin/xyz` or something.  But—just *don't do that*, and then you won't need to get into these technicalities.

---

#### When you need to *send* commits, you need `git push`

Let's say you ran `git fetch origin` and `git fetch upstream`, back to back, and now have *all the commits*.  The Git your laptop is calling `origin` is under your control.  This means you can *send* any *new-to-them* commits *to* `origin`.

Depending on who controls `upstream` and what settings they have made, though, you may not be able to send stuff directly to `upstream`.  We'll worry about that later, because your next goal *may* be to update `master` over on `origin`—which your Git calls `origin/master`.

In fact, you already did this:

> I have used the steps outlined [at https://medium.com/@sahoosunilkumar/how-to-update-a-fork-in-git-95a7daadc14e] to successfully update my master branch of the fork. So the master branch of the fork is now even with the original source's master.

Unfortunately, the stuff at that link is just a recipe.  It doesn't explain *why* the listed commands are listed, leaving you in the situation of Cueball in [this xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1597/):

> "No idea.  Just memorize these shell commands...."

So, let's look closely at `git push`.  While `git push` is as close as Git gets to the opposite of `git fetch`, they're not quite opposites.  The biggest difference is that with `git push`, **there is no notion of a remote-tracking name**.

To use `git push`, you will often run it with two arguments:

- the name of a remote: this supplies the URL, just as with `git fetch`; and
- what Git calls a *refspec*.

The *refspec* is the hard part here.  We can keep it simple, because a branch name works as a refspec.  But we maybe shouldn't keep it this simple, because that neglects something very important.

Note that if you run `git push` *without* these two arguments, the effect depends on whether you have Git 1.x or Git 2.x.  In Git 1.x, `git push` will probably try to push too much.  In Git versions starting with Git 2.0, `git push` defaults to pushing *just the current branch*, which is usually a lot closer to what most users want.

The *remote* part, such as `origin` in `git push origin`, is easy.  It's just the same as before: we're picking who to call up.  The push *command* is going to *send* them commits, which is the obvious counterpart to `git fetch`, which *got commits from them*.  What's really different is this final *refspec* thing.<sup>3</sup>  So we need to define what a refspec is, and how you write one, for `git push`.

The simplest form of a refspec is, as we already noted, just a branch name, such as `master` or `new_branch`.  For `git push`, this is shorthand for `master:master` or `new_branch:new_branch` respectively.

The more complicated form here has a colon in the middle: `master:master` for instance.  The colon separates your *local* name for some commit from the *request you plan to make to the other Git*.

Let's go on now to see how `git push` works:

- First, your Git calls up their Git, just as before.
- But now, instead of having them list out their branch names so that you can *get* all the commits they have that you don't, you have your Git list out *one commit hash ID* for them.  That hash ID is from the left-hand side of your refspec.
- They look at this hash ID and see if they have this commit.  If they do, great!  If not, your Git and their Git go through the same kind of conversation that happened before, to figure out what commits your Git needs to send them.  Your Git will send them *all the commits leading up to this commit* as needed.  They save those somewhere,<sup>4</sup> then go on to the last part.
- For the last part, your Git now gives them polite requests or forceful commands.  These requests-or-commands are of the form:

  - *Please, if it's OK, set your branch name ______ (fill in a name) to ______ (fill in a hash ID).*  Or:
  - *Set your branch name ______ to _______!* Or:
  - *I think your branch name ______ contains hash ID ______.  If so, set it to ______!*

The *branch name* for this last request-or-command comes from the *right* side of the colon.  The commit hash ID comes from the left side, just as with the commits-to-send.  So `git push master:master` takes *your* master—whatever commit hash ID that is—and sends that hash ID over to their Git.  Their Git determines whether they have that commit already, or not, and makes sure to get it if they need it.  Then your Git asks them to set **their branch name**, `master`, to that hash ID.

There are a couple of important things to note here:

- There's no concept of a remote-tracking name.  They aren't going to modify the branch name you say!  If you say `master`, they will set their `master`.  Or maybe they won't, because ...
- They can say *no*.  For a polite request, they'll check first, that your request merely *adds new commits*, or at least doesn't throw any out.  If that's not the case, they will say *no*.  You'll see this as a "rejected (non-fast-forward).
- Even for a forceful command, they can still say *no*.  If you *own* the GitHub repository, they will usually accept a forceful command, but GitHub added a bunch of controls to Git so that you can have them say no.  And, if you *don't* own the GitHub repository, even more controls apply.
- The last form is a sort of conditional command: *I think; if so, I command*.  So they can say no to that one, with an error of the form: "You were wrong."  Because this answer is long, I'm not going to go into detail on this part.

In any case, if they *do* say *OK, I have made the branch-name change, or created a new branch name, as you requested/commanded*, at *this* point, your Git says: *Aha, I should now update my remote-tracking name.*  So if you've convinced `origin`, for instance, to update their `master`, *your* Git will now update your `origin/master` the same way.

---

<sup>3</sup>There is a bunch of history here.  Skipping over all the history, we leave a puzzle: why do we use refspecs with push, but not with fetch?  So let's fill it in a bit.

Technically, the `git fetch` command takes refspecs too.  Before the invention of remotes and remote-tracking names, people sometimes needed (or at least very much wanted) to use refspecs with fetch.  The invention of remote-tracking names got rid of most of the need, but the lack of remote-tracking names with `push` means we still need them with `push`.

Fortunately, remotes and refspecs were invented well before Git became widespread.  The wrong *default* for `git push`, however, persisted through Git 1.7 and 1.8, and some people still use these versions.  (Git 2.0 came out just about the same time as Git 1.9 and 1.9 does not seem to be in use.)

A lone branch name as a refspec has different meaning for `fetch` vs `push`, but since we generally don't put in refspecs when we run `git fetch`, we don't have to worry about that here.

<sup>4</sup>The receiver of a push operation stuffs incoming commits into a "quarantine" location in case they choose, in the end, to reject them.  Older versions of Git lack the quarantine trick but it was pretty important for sites like GitHub.

---

#### Sometimes you want to send, but aren't *allowed* to `git push`

Here, you'll need to make a *pull request*.  This is a GitHub feature: it's not part of Git.  We won't cover it here; there are existing questions and answers for this.  It's worth mentioning, though, that this makes use of the way a GitHub "fork" *remembers the source repository*.  It does not use remote-tracking names, but rather a bunch of stuff that the GitHub folks invented.

### Triangular work: you don't necessarily want to *have* a `master` branch

The purpose of a branch name, in Git, is to be able to locate a specific commit.  Moreover, *given* a branch name, you can use that name with `git checkout` or `git switch`.  This puts your local Git into a state in which you are, as `git status` will say, `on` that branch (`on branch master` or `on branch develop` or whatever).  Once you're in this state, *new* commits you make will *advance* this branch name.  You might have some series of commits ending at the one with hash `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- new_branch (HEAD)
```

You do some work and run `git commit` and *poof*, you have a new commit `I` with parent `H`, and the *branch name* now locates the new commit:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- new_branch (HEAD)
```

The reason you have a `master` on `laptop`, though, is because you ran:

```
git clone <github url for the repository you call origin>
```

and when you did that, your Git called up the Git over at GitHub and copied the *commits* from *that* repository into a new repository.  Then, your (laptop) Git *created* your own local branch name `master`, making it identify the same commit that your (local) Git calls `origin/master` as well:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

You then create your new feature branch, `new_branch`, pointing to commit `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), new_branch, origin/master
```

You check out `new_branch` so that `HEAD` attaches to *that* name:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, new_branch (HEAD), origin/master
```

and then you make your new commit `I`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I   <-- new_branch (HEAD)
```

Notice how, all along, the *remote-tracking* name, `origin/master`, still identifies commit `H`.

Some time now passes.  A bunch of *new* commits get *added* to the repository you forked.  You run `git remote add upstream url`, where *`url`* is the URL for the repository over on GitHub that you forked.  Then you run:

```
git fetch upstream
```

This has your Git call up their Git and get the new commits from them:

```
             J--K--...--T   <-- upstream/master
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I   <-- new_feature (HEAD)
```

**Right now** this is what you are doing (well, have already done):

- First, `git checkout master` attaches your `HEAD` to your `master`.
- Next, `git merge upstream/master` has Git figure out that it can move your branch name `master` forward to point directly to commit `T` (this is a tricky thing that `git merge` does; we haven't covered it here).  The result looks like this:

  ```
               J--K--...--T   <-- master (HEAD), upstream/master
              /
  ...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
              \
               I   <-- new_feature
  ```

  Note how no *commits* have changed.  There are no *new* commits.  All we did was move one label, so that branch name `master` now points to commit `T`.
- Last, `git push origin master` ends up sending commits `J-K-...-T` to *your* GitHub fork, and then asks them to set *their* `master` to point to commit `T`.  Since this is just an add-on (they still don't know about commit `I` but don't care because commits `J` through `T` simply add on), they accept the polite request, and your Git updates your `origin/master`.

The result after that last step is this, in your local (`laptop`) Git:

```
             J--K--...--T   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master, upstream/master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- new_feature
```

But: Suppose we *delete the name `master` entirely*.  We'll start with the same starting point as before, minus the one branch name:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             I   <-- new_branch (HEAD)
```

We'll do `git remote add` if needed and then `git fetch upstream` if needed (we already did both, but let's just pretend we needed to) to get:

```
             J--K--...--T   <-- upstream/master
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             I   <-- new_feature (HEAD)
```

Now, instead of any checkouts, we will just run this:

```
git push origin upstream/master:master
```

The name on the left locates the *commit* we want to send.  This is commit `T`: the last commit on what we're calling `upstream/master`, which is what `upstream`'s Git calls `master`.

The name on the right, `master`, is the name we're going to ask `origin` to set.

The same commits flow to `origin` as before.  They now have the commits up to and including `T` (but they don't have `I`), just as before.  Then we ask them to set their `master` to point to `T`, and they do, and we update our `origin/master`:

```
             J--K--...--T   <-- origin/master, upstream/master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- new_feature (HEAD)
```

The end result is mostly the same.  We did not have to `git checkout master` locally though, so we're still on `new_feature`.

### Rebase

The one remaining problem we have is that our commit `I` has, as its parent, commit `H`.  *We cannot change this!*  Existing commit `I` exists, and has a hash ID.  That commit is forever set in stone.  But what we *can* do is have our Git *compare* the snapshot in commit `I` to that in commit `H`, to see what we *changed*, and make the *same changes* as a *new* commit, that comes after commit `T`.

In other words, Git makes a new commit by *copying* commit `I`.  Let's call this new-and-improved `I`, `I'` (eye-prime), and draw it in:

```
                          I'  <-- ???
                         /
             J--K--...--T   <-- origin/master, upstream/master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- new_feature (HEAD)
```

This process, of copying some commit, is a *cherry-pick* operation in Git, and you can do it with `git cherry-pick`.  If you have several commits in a row to copy, though, the fast and easy way to do this is with `git rebase`.  As a bonus feature, `git rebase` follows up the copying with a branch-name-move.  Note how in the diagram above, we don't have a *name* by which to find our new copy `I'`.  Rebase takes care of that by ripping the *current* branch name off the *last commit we copy* and making it point to that last copy.  In this case, we can draw that as:

```
                          I'  <-- new_feature (HEAD)
                         /
             J--K--...--T   <-- origin/master, upstream/master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   [abandoned]
```

We do lose the easy way to find the hash ID of commit `I`, but that's because we want *our* Git to *abandon* the old commit(s) in favor of the new-and-improved ones.

That's the essence of rebasing.  While I won't go into detail (because again this is so long), to achieve this kind of operation, we generally just run:

```
git rebase <target>
```

In this case the target is commit `T`, which we can find using the name `upstream/master`.  If we've updated `origin`'s `master` so that our `origin/master` locates commit `T` too, we can use `git rebase origin/master`, but `git rebase upstream/master` will work fine.

If we've kept our `master` branch name, and updated it, we can use `git rebase master` as well.  The key is that we need to tell `git rebase` to locate commit `T`.  *Any* name that finds commit `T` will be fine, here.  In fact, we can even use `T`'s hash ID, if we want to cut-and-paste it with the mouse for instance.

Now, if you ever ran `git push origin new_branch` *before*, you have already sent commit `I` to the Git over at `origin`.  If you now attempt to send commit `I'` to `origin` and get the Git over at `origin` to point *their* name `new_branch` to commit `I'`, they will say *no!*

The reason they say no is that this polite request is asking them to *discard* some original commit(s) in favor of their new-and-improved replacements.  *Your* Git already did this, when you ran `git rebase`.  But now you need to get *their* Git, over at `origin`, to do the same.  **This means you must use a force push operation.**

You may have read that force-pushes are bad.  They *are*.  But we're faced with two bad alternatives: you can leave your pull request behind, or you can abandon the original commits in favor of these new-and-supposedly-improved replacements.  If *you* abandon the originals, you need to convince *everyone else who has copied these commits into their Git repositories* to do the same.

Some people prefer to leave the pull request behind.  There's nothing fundamentally wrong with that either.  But if your company, or your personal preference, dictates that you should rebase, do it, and then use `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease`.  (To find out the precise difference between these two, search StackOverflow.)